# Can we feed a value without defining tf.placeholder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Here is the code https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py,I wonder why we can feed the model by:

```
cost, state, _ = session.run([m.cost, m.final_state, eval_op],
                              {m.input_data: x,
                               m.targets: y,
                               m.initial_state: state})
```

Because `initial_state` isn't with `tf.placeholder`,so how can we feed it?

In the code, it defines a class. And defines `self._initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, data_type())`, then `state = self._initial_state`, and `(cell_output, state) = cell(inputs[:, time_step, :], state)`. After that, `self._final_state = state`. What's more, it defines a function in the class:

`@property
  def final_state(self):
    return self._final_state`

And here comes

```
state = m.initial_state.eval()
cost, state, _ = session.run([m.cost, m.final_state, eval_op],
                             {m.input_data: x,
                              m.targets: y,
                              m.initial_state: state})
```

And I have ran the code locally, it quite have the difference without `state` in feeddict.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because initial_state isn't with `tf.placeholder`,so how can we feed it?

Placeholder is just a tensorflow tensor; we can feed any tensor using `feed_dict` mechanism,

> And I have ran the code locally, it quite have the difference without state in feed_dict.

Here if you don't feed the learned state from previous batch, state will be initialized as zero for the next batch, hence there will be degradation of results.

Comment: Yes, you are right. And I have been told that the feed value can replace the same name tensor in graph because of the feed_dict mechanism. But I am still confused, is the answer means we have to loop the state when we use rnn and lstm? I have read many example codes of rnn and lstm, which simply uses `initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, data_type())`.  And if there are other ways that we can loop the state besides by a class? Thanks a lot.